# Add a property restriction, using an anonymous class, using Apache Jena

Tags: owl, jena, restriction

I am trying to add the following fragment to a .owl file that I create in Prótegé:

```
<owl: Class rdf: about = "http://www.semanticweb.org/example/ontologies/2021/8/test#subs_de_sp3">
        <owl: equivalentClass>
            <owl: Class>
                <owl: intersectionOf rdf: parseType = "Collection">
                    <rdf: Description rdf: about = "http://www.semanticweb.org/example/ontologies/2021/8/test#subsymptom" />
                    <owl: Restriction>
                        <owl: onProperty rdf: resource = "http://www.semanticweb.org/example/ontologies/2021/8/test#is_symptom_of" />
                        <owl: hasValue rdf: resource = "http://www.semanticweb.org/example/ontologies/2021/8/test#sp3" />
                    </ owl: Restriction>
                </ owl: intersectionOf>
            </ owl: Class>
        </ owl: equivalentClass>
    </ owl: Class>
```

I have read https://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/ but cannot complete the task. I have come this far:

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
        OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel (OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM_RULE_INF, null);
        InputStream ontologyIn = FileManager.get (). Open ("~ / jena_example / ontologies / symptom_rdf.owl");
        model.read (ontologyIn, "RDF / XML");
        OntClass anon class = model.createClass ();
        OntClass class = model.getOntClass (NS + "subsymptom");
        class.addEquivalentClass (classanon);
```

How can I complete the task? I would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you just have to follow this, or not: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/#more-complex-class-expressions - I mean, your restriction is a complex class expression. Did you try this part of the docs already? If so, what didn't work as intended?

Comment: The method you need is indeed then https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/ontology/OntModel.html#createHasValueRestriction(java.lang.String,org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Property,org.apache.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode) for the value restriction and the intersection has to be provided by an RDFList as you can see in the "Intersection, union and complement class expressions" chapter of the documentation

Comment: @UninformedUser Yes, there is the answer (https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/ontology/OntModel.html#createHasValueRestriction(java.lang.String,org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Property,org.apache.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode)), Thank you very much